# Коллекция примитивов в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

В моей модели (code-first) есть коллекции примитивов (string, int), которые не могут быть сохранены в БД в чистом виде и для которых оборачивание их в классы, создание отдельных таблиц и настройка связей было бы слишком громоздким делом.
Есть соображения обернуть их в сложный тип, но в этом случае, как я понимаю, все равно придется в этом типе создавать свойство типа коллекции.
Как можно поступить?

Comment: Если у вас и правда Code First - то создание отдельных таблиц не может быть слишком сложным. 1 класс с 2 свойствами - это же всего 4 строчки кода...

Comment: А обязательно использовать sql? Как вариант для хранения данных такого типа есть специальная бд - redis. Предназначена для хранения данных в виде "ключ-значение".

Comment: если коллекции маленькие, то может в виде текста в json-формате хранить их в столбце типа STRING?

Comment: В Entity Framework нельзя так смапить, там есть ValueObject но с массивами там придется извращатся.

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно часто приходится рассматривать подобные коллекции как ValueObject и не делать под них отдельные таблицы (по привычке как раз руки тянутся сделать отдельную таблицу).

В EF поддержки коллекций нет, но она легко эмулируется.

На примере `string[]`:

```
public class Contact
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public string[] Phones
    {
        get
        {
            var tab = this.PhonesDb.Split(',');
            return tab.ToArray();
        }
        set
        {
            this.PhonesDb = string.Join(",", value);
        }
    }

    public string PhonesDb { get; set; }
}
```

Можно хранить в json'е:

```
public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string AltNamesJson
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.AltNames); }
        set { this.AltNames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(value); }
    }

    public string[] AltNames { get; set; }
}
```

Больше примеров можно поискать в этом полезном посте: [How to store double[] array to database with Entity Framework Code-First approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15220921/5752652)

Comment: [немного ссылки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/backing-field)