# Размещение динамической модели в базе данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2

Следующая ситуация:
В базе данных есть таблица для кастомных логов которая хранит в себе информацию об изменениях в некоторых местах программы, например юзеров.
Сейчас же в этой таблицу нужно реализовать не только логи по юзерах, но и логи по изменениях автомобилей.

Так как это Entity Framework и тут есть возможность реализовать lazy loading, появился вопрос: Возможно ли сделать динамическую ентити с динамическими связями?

Даный вопрос относится чисто к размышлениям, которые возникли в последствии изучения C# core.

Comment: Если под "...динамическую ентити с динамическими связями" понимать создание сущностей и связей между ними во время выполнения программы, то нет, такое невозможно.

Answer (score 0):

Простите, а зачем? Таблица логов должна состоять из поля с датой, типом события и [поля в формате json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/500734/213987), куда динамически засовывать diff полей. Что вам даст подгрузка сущности, которая уже поменялась пять редакций подряд?

И вообще говоря, технически EF заточен под описание структуры в compile time, а не на генерацию структуры на лету в рантайме.

Comment: вот к примеру, если тип лога User то мне надо вывести юзернейм или другую инфу по юзеру, если тип лога Car - бренд автомобиля. Тут и вопрос, как динамические связи реализовать?