# Entity Framework, добавить динамически новую таблицу

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Имеется задача где необходимо во время выполнения создавать новую таблицу по запросу юзера. Таблицу заранее предсказать нельзя, т.е. я не знаю ни количество полей, ни их названия и ограничения. Есть ли какой-то способ генерировать и добавлять в БД новую таблицу по входящим данным во время выполнения ?

Comment: так сделайте две таблицы, в одной храните наименование таблицы а во второй список полей и значений этой таблицы

Comment: Вероятно, вам нужно EAV или подобные подходы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/933610/184217

Answer (score 1):

Update 2020:

См. концепт в статье на хабре: [Roslyn & EF Core: конструируем DbContext в runtime](https://habr.com/en/post/500102/)

---

Предыдущий ответ:

Средствами Entity Framework (что в 6, что в core) такое сделать нельзя. Не предназначен для этого EF, особенно с учётом постоянно крена в сторону подхода Code First.

Максимум, что вы можете сделать - это написать свой sql-запрос ("CREATE TABLE...") и выполнить его - будет вам создана таблица.

Но схему базы это на лету не обновит и строить linq-запросы по этим таблицам вы не сможете.

Был [схожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/885445/213987), но задубликатить не даёт.