# Добавить массив string в MSQL через EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть много таблиц в CSV надо на их основе создать таблицы в MSQL.
Устанавливаю соединение:

```
public class HouseContext : DbContext 
{
    public HouseContext()
        : base("DBConnection") 
    { }

    public DbSet<string[]> Houses { get; set; } //Таблица Houses
}
```

Пытаюсь создать таблицу с названиями столбцов

```
string[] rows = new string[]{"Id", "Adress", "Length"};
using (HouseContext db = new HouseContext())
{
    db.Houses.Add(rows);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

И тут он вылетает с ошибкой. Подскажите что не так?

Comment: DbSet<string[]>?? в DbSet нужно указать наименование сущности

Comment: @pashagoroshko пробывал и так. Создавал объект с массивом внутри так же выдает ошибку. А создавать на каждый массив кучу свойств. Не вариант.

Comment: массив нельзя кстати так создавать, попробуйте создать объект в котором будет свойство типа string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Массив строк не является допустим типом, возможно только указание своего класса, в котором будет описана структура, что-то типа:

```
public DbSet<House> Houses { get; set; } //Таблица Houses
```

где House:

```
public class House
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
}
```

То есть вам нужно описать какие поля у таблицы и [сделать это на этапе компиляции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/885445/213987).

Также у вас есть альтернативы.

Во-первых, массив строк можно хранить в специальном поле в формате json.

Во-вторых, можно сериализовать подобным образом: [Коллекция примитивов в Entity Framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/500734/213987)

Рекомендую почитать какие-нибудь учебники по EF, по вашему вопросу видно, что вы слабо представляете как работает EF.

Вот тут неплохой: https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/