# Поле для Uri в EntityFramework с подходом CodeFirst

Tags: c#, база-данных, sql-server, entity-framework, codefirst

Есть такой класс в модели

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri WebPage { get; set; }
}
```

Я хочу создать БД с помощью EF6 и подхода CodeFirst [вот так](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.2.php). Соответственно просто обращаюсь к БД в следующим образом:

```
 using (UserContext db = new UserContext())
        {
            // создаем два объекта User
            Uri uri1 = new Uri(@"http:\\www.egg.egg");
            Uri uri2 = new Uri(@"http:\\www.foo.egg");
            User user1 = new User { Name = "Tom", WebPage = uri1 }; // Age = 33 };
            User user2 = new User { Name = "Sam", WebPage = uri2 };//Age = 26 };
            // добавляем их в бд
            db.Users.Add(user1);
            db.Users.Add(user2);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

Но тип Uri не транслируется в типы MsSql напрямую и возникает исключение:

> error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 6:No mapping specified for properties User.WebPage in Set Users.
>   An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:

Вопрос - как это сделать правильно? Буду благодарен за ссылку на учебный материал.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда тип не транслируется в sql напрямую - то самое простое - сделать два свойства, одно `[NotMapped]` с нужным вам типом (Uri в данном случае), а второе - тип, про который знает база (обычно - строка), который будете сохранять в бд.

Примерно как здесь: [Коллекция примитивов в Entity Framework](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/500734/213987)

У вас так:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Uri WebPage
    {
        get
        {
            return new Uri(this.WebPageDb);
        }
        set
        {
            this.WebPageDb = this.ToString();
        }
    }

    [Column("WebPage")]
    public string WebPageDb { get; set; }
}
```