# Возможно ли сериализовать List или массив в БД?

Tags: c#, sql-server

База MS SQL.Использую Entity Framework.Нужно Лист или Массив сохранить в базу данных.Как это реализовать.Приведите пример пожалуйста

Comment: Вы хотите сохранить весь массив в _одну ячейку_? Или в разные ячейки одной _колонки_? Или, может, вообще в разные ячейки одной строки?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov в одну ячейку одной колонки

Comment: уже задавался подобный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/500734/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-entity-framework

Comment: главное чтобы потом не появился тут вопрос, как отфильтровать данные в таблице по какому-то значению из этого массива/поля