# Entity Framework Core создать базу данных из xsd

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Есть приложение на ASP.NET Core 2, необходимо сгенерировать базу данных на основании xsd файла. Первоначально перевожу с помощью утилиты xsd2code++ xsd в набор классов (при этом выбираю опцию TargetFramework - ASP Core). При генерации контекста данных получаю следующую ошибку

> 'The property 'property_name' could not be mapped, because it is of
>   type 'List<'string>' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid
>   entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using
>   the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in
>   'OnModelCreating'.'

Comment: Вопрос неспецифичен для xsd, удалил метку. Вот тут решение: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/500734/213987 - просто создайте NotMapped поле

Comment: @AK а возможно как то в автоматическом режиме? возможно есть настройки в этой утилите? или только руками?

Comment: Я думаю, что только руками, так как а) я не видел подобного в xsd2code и б) эта тулза вообще никаких завязок на EF не имеет.

Comment: @AK спасибо, а есть что то на EF подобное?

Comment: AFAIK нету. Но не ручаюсь, что я прямо знаю всё-всё, относящееся к EF.