# Коллекция примитивов в Entity Framework без загрязнения модели

Tags: c#, архитектура, entity-framework-core, чистый-код

Когда-то давно я [описывал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/789093/213987) типовой способ сохранения коллекции примитивов в базе для EF:

```
public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string AltNamesJson
    {
        get { return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.AltNames); }
        set { this.AltNames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(value); }
    }

    public string[] AltNames { get; set; }
}
```

И на текущий момент меня такой подход уже не устраивает. Я не хочу загрязнять домен лишней зависимостью от Json.Net (как способа сериализации), в идеале вообще не хочу тащить в домен знание о том, как модель хранится - пусть это знание находится в проекте Persistence. И не хочу в модель тащить ненужные поля с NotMapped:

```
public class Brand
{
    public Brand(int id, string name, string[] altNames)
    {
        this.ID = id;
        this.Name = name;
        this.AltNames = altNames;
    }

    public int ID { get; private set; }

    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public string[] AltNames { get; private set; }
}
```

Использую EF Core 3.0.

Как бы провернуть такую операцию? Это вообще возможно?

Сам посматриваю в сторону [Shadow Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties) + Fluent Api

[Тут Аршинов упоминает](https://habr.com/en/company/jugru/blog/503868/), что ОРМ всё лучше начинают работать с конструкторами, но что-то не понимаю, как де/сериализовать модель в базу.

Comment: если так https://nightbaker.github.io/ef/core,/fluent/api,/.net/core/2019/02/12/ef-core-array-property/ ?

Comment: Ну и тащить JSON.NET в домен не обязательно, можно сделать зависимость от своего какого-то интерфейса IJsonConverter или IArrayConverter и проталкивать потом уже легковесный адаптер от JsonNet или от чего угодно

Comment: @4per Кажется, ValueConverter  - это то, что нужно! Спасибо за наводку, вообще тянет на ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо @4per [за подсказку](https://nightbaker.github.io/ef/core,/fluent/api,/.net/core/2019/02/12/ef-core-array-property/), сделал на базе ValueConverter:

```
public class BrandConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Brand>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Brand> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(e => e.AltTitles)
               .HasConversion(JsonValueConverter());
    }

    private static ValueConverter<string[], string> JsonValueConverter()
    {
        return new ValueConverter<string[], string>(
            v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
            v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(v)
        );
    }
}
```

Документация:

- [Microsof EF Core Value Conversions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions)
- [Microsof ValueConverter<TModel,TProvider> Class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.storage.valueconversion.valueconverter-2?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev16.query%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion.ValueConverter%602);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-3.1)