# Возможность добавления нескольких значений в одно поле SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, sql-server

Вкратце вопрос: Как реализовать возможность многоразового использования поля?
Например, у меня в БД SQL Server есть несколько полей (фамилия, имя, отчество, email и номер телефона), не могу понять, как можно для одного пользователя добавить возможность использования поля номер телефона и email не однократно, а несколько раз, как в контактах на телефоне, если захотел, то добавил ещё один номер. Нужно использовать инструкцию INSERT или какие-то другие решения?

Comment: это вам решать, можно черер точку с запятой писать в то же поле, а можно отдельную таблицу для емейлов юзера сделать

Comment: Ну, хм, если через точку с запятой, то таблица не будет даже в [первой нормальной форме](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0). Индексы и всё такое от этого тоже не очень выиграют, и как с джойнами быть, непонятно. Классическое решение всё же через дополнительную таблицу.

Comment: @VladD а зачем нормальная форма? Если поле не для поиска, а только хранения, то вполне можно хранить хлам в одной колонке.

Comment: использовать что-то типа: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/500734/213987 (Можно сериализовать через String.Join или через json - по вкусу, хоть в xml).  При этом действительно по этим полям не сделать нормальный поиск, индексов не будет, т.к. это не первая нормальная форма -- чисто для хранения хлама, который не понадобится, согласен с обоими предыдущими комментаторами.

Comment: @AzizUmarov: Ну если пользоваться колонкой как BLOB'ом, то всё равно. Но обычно сила базы данных как раз в том, что она видит данные, и может выполнять с ними CRUD-операции сама.

Comment: @VladD не спорю, сила в этом самом. Но если нет необходимости то почему не Blob. Я вот не думаю что все используют молоток по предназначению.

Comment: Большое спасибо за совет! Буду использовать отдельную таблицу т.к. нужна ещё возможность поиска по любому полю. Результат пришлю сюда в ответ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз вы хотите использовать поиск, по идее ваши таблицы должны выглядеть как-то так:

```sql
CREATE TABLE People
(
    Id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(MAX),
    CONSTRAINT PK_People_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

CREATE TABLE Emails
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    PersonId INT NOT NULL,
    Email VARCHAR(512),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Emails_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Emails_People FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
        REFERENCES People (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE Phones
(
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    PersonId INT NOT NULL,
    Phone VARCHAR(128),
    CONSTRAINT PK_Phones_Id PRIMARY KEY (Id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_Phones_People FOREIGN KEY (PersonId)
        REFERENCES People (Id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
);
```

Таким образом, у вас возникают две дополнительные таблицы Emails и Phones, которые могут содержат по нескольку емэйлов/телефонов для каждого человека. Клауза ON DELETE CASCADE нужна для того, чтобы при удалении человека автоматически удалялись и его email'ы/телефоны.

Ваши данные при этом будут выглядеть так:

| Id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Вася |
| 2 | Иннокентий |

| Id | PersonId | Email |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | vasya@example.com |
| 11 | 1 | basil@example.com |
| 12 | 1 | vasily.alibabaevich@example.com |
| 13 | 2 | kesha@example.com |
| 14 | 2 | parrot@example.com |

(Насчёт оптимальности SQL не уверен, *я ненастоящий сварщик*.)

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Именно то, что было нужно, по логике!

Comment: @straightboy: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 3):

Я любитель собирать разные способы сделать что-либо. И у меня есть чем поделиться.

1. Да, можно хранить несколько значений в одном поле таблицы. Когда-то давно, когда компьютеры были большими, а программы для них маленькими, этот способ реально использовался.

   Например, в книге Кена Хендерсона "Профессиональное руководство по Transact-SQL" такой подход описан в главе 10. Массивы. Но там прямо сказано, что это нарушает правила нормализации. И сейчас лучше так не делать.
2. Во многих современных РСУБД есть возможность использования XML или JSON. SQL Server умеет работать и с тем, и с другим. Причём для этих типов данных можно применять поиск, схему, индексы, что делает их использование намного удобнее в сравнении с первым способом.
3. Использовать дополнительную таблицу. То, что описано в соседнем ответе. В первую очередь следует смотреть на этот способ. И лишь если возникает необходимость хранения данных, типы и количество которых неизвестны заранее, следует прибегать к JSON.

Comment: Большое спасибо! К сожалению не могу добавить репутацию к вашему ответу, не позволяет сайт. Хорошие советы, очень признателен, узнал больше, чем в своем начальном курсе по БД :)

Comment: @straightboy: Сейчас у вас репутация выросла, по идее голосовать уже можете

Comment: @VladD: Спасибо, вроде получилось!)